# RegEx to Match *ONLY* IPv6 Global Unicast Addresses (GUA) from logs

Tags: networking, grep, regular-expression, ipv6

There's next to no tools for IPv6 security, so want to roll my own solution which I will later opensource. SO: I need a RegEx to sift through logs for remote IPv6 connections to analyze and process them for potential blocking on a very busy server with chunky logs. Therefore I'm really only interested in a RegEx to match for **REAL** (actual) IPv6 Global Unicast Addresses ("***GUA***"). Since there's no value in blocking invalid ones, validating IPv6 address construction is nice, but not essential.

### Why this is (somewhat) Challenging:

Due to the way IPv6 addresses are compressed- leading zeros are compressed- addresses can be divided by single colons as well as single semicolons **AND** one set of double semicolons. ***And the double pair of semicolons can appear in different places depending on how the address compression happens!*** Finally, the number of address characters separated by the colons are also variable.

So the target of the RegEx I'm looking for can look like any one of the few examples below:

```
2001:db8:800:400::130
2001:db8:800:400::2:135
2001:db8:d::55:1
2001:db8:1ff:8c0:151:164:108:23
```

I think the above really illustrates the difficulty of constructing a RegEx to match this mess.

### Expected Output of RegEx:

- **Precise**: Matches **ONLY** valid GUA addresses; not partial GUAs or local ones in the log.
- **Single `grep` Only**: no piping `grep`'s through `grep`'s through `grep`'s...
- **Performant**: RegEx's can be CPU intensive. An answer (now deleted) ran for nearly 3 hours without completing before I had to kill it.
- **Tested**: It's trivial to test, so please ensure your RegEx matches correctly before posting. Sounds obvious, but...

### Example:

```
grep "your RegEx Goes Here" /var/log/messages | sort -u
```

Should provide a lovely list of GUA addresses, run quickly, correctly & performantly.

[Specimen grep with output showing the desired output](https://pastebin.com/FBvzU9B8)

### Optional:

The regex should at least identify real, complete GUA IPv6 addresses found in `/var/log/messages`.  **HOWEVER**: if your RegEx could validate any input to determine if address construction is valid, that would be even better!

Please post a [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/) with your test results so all can review & compare results.  I'll run all RegExs posted on the same server to compare their results & performance. The best- most performant and accurate- RegEx will be used in the opensource solution and due credit given to the genius.

Comment: All comments have been deleted. If you _must_ continue your discussion, take it to the [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109206/discussion-on-question-by-f1linux-regex-to-match-only-ipv6-global-unicast-addr).

Answer (score 1):

### UPDATE:

After ***@ilkkachu*** identified my previous RegEx was missing ranges, I've went back to tthe drawing board and completely rewrote it from scratch and tested it auditing a sample of the 4300+ results. The pastebin containing the new results are also updated for your review. Looks righteous, but best to let clean independent eyeballs judge that.

### NOTE:

The below RegEx has been tested and found to work correctly for the GUA addressing specified IANA's Global Address Unicast Assignments with the exception of `3000:0000::/4`, `3ffe::/16` and `5f00::/8`. The latter 2 ranges are used for the 6 bone- now deprecated and these ranges returned, and the `3000:0000::/4` is reserved, not found in the wild and might conceivably never be used. So I had addressed these issues when settling on a RegEx. Down-votes are welcome if they are accompanied by feedback where an error is observed. Indeed, I post here to have my thinking critically reviewed; not rubber-stamped ;-)

### SOLUTION:

All the other questions I found on various Stack sites on RegEx's for IPv6 cast too wide a net and match the kitchen sink of IPv6 addressing. If one is going to be using the output of the `grep` for IP blacklisting (my ultimate goal), well, the lack of precision could be a big problem. Surprisingly, searching Google didn't yield any fruit either.

**So: to save others wasting cycles solving the same problem, here's what I've come up with to match only a IPv6 GUA address**:

```
time grep -Eo "2[0-9a-fA-F]{3}:(([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}[:]{1,2}){1,6}[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4})" /var/log/messages | sort -u >> /root/GUA-RegEx-Results.txt
```

### TESTING:

The RegEx- from my testing on a ***very** busy DNS server- seems to effectively match [IANA's Global Address Unicast Assignments](https://www.iana.org/assignments/ipv6-unicast-address-assignments/ipv6-unicast-address-assignments.xhtml). When testing, I was specifically looking for errors relating to:

- Partial GUA address

### TEST RESULTS:

No such errors were observed and my results can be reviewed [here](https://pastebin.com/FBvzU9B8)
(**Please Note**: *no inference should be made about abuse from any addresses in this pastebin listing*).

**Tools used to validate results**:

[IPv6 CIDR Calculator](https://www.ultratools.com/tools/ipv6CIDRToRangeResult?ipAddress=2a0b%3Af4c2%3A%3A1&as_sfid=AAAAAAVKU_ABe-BMRAcU6Ar9-ZR1yH04iDJZ0kfT2UFvPicLD4TWKSMETOPY1xlYT2040b0NasXEN8fIuaby4EfV2XyUf5bsul1RP80oCQj5FG5uUI3L413h2rRGJpByCFoucg4%3D&as_fid=14c37fd9508700f665262412c4891f76fb34a6c7)

[IPv6 Address Assignment Checker](https://www.ipaddress.com/ipv6/2a0b%3Af4c2%3A%3A1)

Just copy and past addresses to see if you find a clanger at the above links

### PERFORMANCE:

To sift a 1.5GB /var/log/messages file, the following performance was observed:

**Valid Unique IPv6 Addresses Found**:

- 4345

**Speed**:

- real  0m56.346s
- user  0m28.916s
- sys   0m0.328s

If you have anything tighter & more elegant (*Geeks love a interesting RegEx challenge, let's face it*), by all means, contribute it in an answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109127/discussion-between-isaac-and-f1linux).